# How to export app metrics using prometheus client from an Django app running as an uwsgi server?

Tags: python, django, uwsgi, prometheus

I read the docs of prometheus client https://github.com/prometheus/client_python/#multiprocess-mode-gunicorn
where it mentions to expose metrics in a multi-process mode in python. Instead of Gunicorn, I am running django app via uwsgi. Similar to that in the docs I added code in my project's wsgi.py -

```
class WSGIEnvironment(WSGIHandler):
def __call__(self, environ, start_response):

    **registry = CollectorRegistry()
    multiprocess.MultiProcessCollector(registry)
    data = generate_latest(registry)**
    django.setup()
    return super(WSGIEnvironment, self).__call__(environ, 
    start_response)
application = WSGIEnvironment()
```

But exposing collected data via this method did not look feasible to me. Hence I exposed an api in my Django app /metrics which invokes metrics view -

```
def metrics(request):

    registry = CollectorRegistry()
    multiprocess.MultiProcessCollector(registry)
    data = generate_latest(registry)
    print "data", data
    return HttpResponse(
        data,
        content_type=CONTENT_TYPE_LATEST)
```

Still I cannot view the metrics being exposed by my app. Is there any configuration required? I think I am missing very basic thing.

Comment: You must not create a new collector and registry every time you call the view. Put the variables in the module namespace (outside of any function or class) and have only one copy.

Comment: Creating the MultiProcessCollector and registry is fine actually, if a tad inefficient.

Comment: @KlausD. - thanks for the suggestion. I put these variables outside of the function. however my application is breaking at library level while collecting metrics whenever I am hitting my /metrics api. Exception type - **'NoneType' object has no attribute 'endswith'**. It is failing at  **for metric in collector.collect():**. Is there any other addition which I am missing like 'prometheus_multiproc_dir'?

Comment: I has a similar problem in a project recently. AFAIR I das to rearrange things to get rid of it. Now I have a `prometheus.py` with `multiprocess.MultiProcessCollector(core.REGISTRY, mkdtemp())` and some Gauges and in the view just `generate_latest()`.

Comment: @KlausD. Isn't calling `mkdtemp()` in multiprocess code (across many uWSGI workers) gonna create separate temp dirs which would defeat the purpose of storing data from multiple workers in one place?

Also, how are you removing this temp directory, since Prometheus recommends it should be cleared on every app start.

Answer (score 0):

That looks indeed quite good. I've got it working in a similar way, by just creating a view (exactly like you posted it) and without modifying the `wsgi.py`.

The `/metrics` view will serve an **empty page** if there are no metrics found.
If you see an empty page, there might be something wrong recording the metrics.
If you see a 404, then there is something wrong with your `urls.py`.

One common mistake is to call a counter without increasing it:

```
# right
my_counter.labels(my_label='a').inc()

# wrong
my_counter.labels(my_label='a')
```

Hope that helps.